# Excluding the setup method of a junit test using ant

Tags: ant, junit

Hi I am new to junit and ant.

I want to prevent the JUnit @Before* annotated methods from execution.

Is that possible with Ant's "exclude"?

Are other possibilities to prevent these annotated methods from execution?

thx

Comment: why don't you delete the @Before* tag?

Comment: Can you expand on why exactly you'd want to do this? There is almost certainly a better way of achieving your end goal.

Comment: I record the script using Selenium IDE and export it as junit source.In the exported source the port,browser and base url are fixed.I want to give the option to the users to sellect the browser in which the want to execute their script.If u have any ways to achieve this please do suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't do that with Ant's exclude.

You could use Ant to change the annotation in all files.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html

```
<replace dir="${tests}" token="@Before" value="@BeforeREMOVED">
  <include name="**/*.java"/>
  <exclude name="**/*Test*"/>
</replace>
```

You can adjust/omit the include and exclude tags as necessary to match the files you want.

You can alway change the files back

```
<replace dir="${tests}" token="@BeforeREMOVED" value="@Before">
  <include name="**/*.java"/>
  <exclude name="**/*Test*"/>
</replace>
```

Otherwise you can extend the tests with a new class that overrides the methods.  Seems like it might be a lot of work though.